# Sending JavaScript Array or Object to Django View

Tags: ajax, django

I am trying to send via AJAX an array (or object) to my Django View.

**In JS File**:

```
    var dataArr = [];
    dataArr.push({'status':'active'});
    ...
    var json = JSON.stringify(dataArr);
    ...
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/filter/",
        data: {
            'filter_text' : json,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: filterSuccess,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });
```

I am getting a 403 Forbidden error in Javascript. I tried several things, e.g. omitting the dataType / contentType, sending a Javascript object instead of an array, etc.

Comment: Do you pass csrf token to your post request? Or use csrf_exempt?

Comment: Try to add `@csrf_exempt` decorator to your view and if it will work - the problem is in `$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()`. Are you sure the token is being sent at all? Try to use `console.log($("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val())` before ajax method.

Comment: You can just add `'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'`

Comment: The middleware token was already there. I am simply using the following ajax call and am using the array itself - this did the trick for me:

        `$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/filter/",
            traditional: true,
            data: {
                'status_filter' : statusArr,
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: filterSuccess,
        });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the array directly to url,

Use `jQuery.param(yourObject)`.

The param() method creates a serialized representation of an array or an object that can be understandable by various frameworks like php, ruby, django etc.

For again converting it to python

```
from urllib import parse
value = parse.parse_qs(self.request.POST.get('name'))
```

Note that using prase you can lost some information, so recheck your data after getting it in python.